# Errors upgrading .NET Core app to 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

So, I have a happily working ASP.NET Core 1.0 app targeting net461 framework.

Today I tried to upgrade it to the new ASP.NET Core 1.1 (according to the instructions [on this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) all you need to do is a Nuget package upgrade)

This resulted in the following slew of errors:

```
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (>= 4.3.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'System.Reflection.Metadata (>= 1.4.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors (>= 1.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.
...
```

what am I missing here? Shouldn't this just work?

For reference, here are the relevant sections of the project.json (before running the Nuget upgrade):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
       "imports": [
      ]
    }
  }
```

EDIT: after running the Nuget upgrade, the dependencies section was changed to this by Visual Studio:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: Did you download the 1.1 SDK/Tools?

Comment: Can you post your project.json dependencies section after updating nuget packages ?

Comment: Yep, installed the 1.1 SDK (it shows up as "Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2.1-03177 (x64)" in Add/Remove Programs)
Also, added new dependencies section to the post

Comment: What does `dotnet restore` in a command prompt tells you?

Comment: Also, update `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools` to `1.1.0-preview4-final` as well.

Comment: Try to create a new project, update to 1.1.0 and check if it works. I just did this here and it worked. I installed the `.Net core 1.1.0` and the `.NET Core 1.0.1 – VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2`

Comment: Just experienced the same problem upgrading a 1.0 project using net461. The error I get is "The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"

Comment: Got it to work for now by removing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools

Comment: Tried creating a new project, this time targeting netcoreapp1.0, and got the same errors trying to do the nuget package upgrade...

Comment: @chaiwalla don't remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final`, just move it to the `tools` section instead of `dependencies`. (Juste create a new project you will see how is the `project.json` file)

Comment: @JérômeMével VS2017 does not create projects with a project.json? I removed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final` as well and everything is now working fine, when I had it just in the tools section my EF Core migrations would no longer work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out, in case anyone else has the same problem.

There were three steps to make it work:

1. For some reason, the standard **"Microsoft and .NET"** Nuget feed was not including these packages.. I had to open the Nuget Settings and tick the **"nuget.org"** feed as well. Having done that it was able to restore the v1.1 packages
2. The blog post that I was referencing didn't mention that you need to open your `global.json` file and change the SDK Version to `"1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"` (for some reason, v1.1 still has an SDK called v1.0.0 -- any ideas what's going on there?!?)
3. Having done those two things, trying to run the app produced a 500 error, but after enabling `stdoutLogEnabled` in web.config you can see the exception is:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

To solve this, you need to delete your application's `bin` folder and then rebuild (for some reason "Rebuild Solution" isn't enough). When you deploy to Production, presumably you'll also need to delete the bin folder there or you might get the same problem.

Comment: #1 alone got it working for me - although I had to restart VS for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected something similar to what @gallivantor mentioned in his #1, but somehow something kept rewriting the `NuGet.config` file behind the UI and when I re-started Visual Studio per @jim-w's suggestion, the `NuGet.org` item would go back to un-checked.

So I decided to look into the `NuGet.config` file and noticed that there were two sections: `<packageSources>` and `<disabledPackageSources>`. And the source with the `NuGet.org` key was in both. I tried to remove it from the disabled packages section and everything started working.

Before:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" /> <!-- This is what I was referring to -->
  </disabledPackageSources>
</configuration>
```

After:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Warning: I omitted a number of details (in particular about the environment) to keep the answer simple. Before applying this solution to your situation make sure it is appropriate to your circumstances.